# Windows 10 Internet connectivity issue

Tags: windows-10, networking

This is a very strange issue that I am having.Yesterday my computer sort of reset itself. What I mean by this is that when I turned it on the computer started up and took me through the initial setup process of Windows 10. It had completely undone all of my personalization, it had deleted all my user data like documents and pictures. Luckily I use OneDrive as a backup, so that was all fine. More interesting though, is this issue I am having connecting to the internet.

I can connect using the Tor browser just fine. That is how I am writing this. I can download various things, either from Steam or iTunes, etc. The only problem I am having accessing the Internet is with my web browsers. Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and even Internet Explorer just will not connect to most websites. Chrome will connect to a couple like Redit and Netflix, even Facebook. All of the Google owned sites do not work. Tor however works perfectly on all sites.

Final piece of the puzzle, this is not a DNS issue. I have reset my DNS settings, changed the DNS settings, no change. I can ping websites using the command line just fine. It has no issue resolving the sites IPs. I can connect to these sites using other computers on the same network and DNS.

So far I have tried resetting my network settings in Windows, I have done a CMOS clear, I set my IPv6 to different DNS, even though I do not have IPv6 on my network. I have updated my PC. None of this has worked. Any advice at all would be appreciated. I have Googled around a bit, but it looks like everyone else with this issue cannot ping out to these websites. I can send pings just fine, so I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Try uninstalling the Network card driver (have the driver package on hand before doing this).  Restart and reinstall / preferably upgrade the driver. When doing this, update BIOS at the same time unless it is already the current version)

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: You may need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the second link on the page, run in place and Keep Everything.